# How to avoid CS1591 warning in Visual Studio Mac for Unity solution?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, xamarin

There are over 2000 warnings in CS1591, like [image]

And I googled a lot, but I find `Project Options` is disabled, and I can't find any clue in Solution Options.

So how could I avoid the CS1591 warning in Visual Studio Mac edition in a Unity Project?

[image: project menu]

Comment: You don't do it for the solution, you do it for the project.

Comment: @DavidG as you can see, Project Options is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to do this, change the project file by text editor add `<NoWarn>1591</NoWarn>` into it.

You can find more in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715718.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma warning disable CS1591
```

but that might seem tedious adding to that to each file